# How to switch product image for same product but in diffrent categories in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, e-commerce, elementor

I am new to WordPress and woo commerce and working on phone back cover project which have phone brands as categories and phone models as subcategories, Now my problem is I want to upload a single product which will be available in all subcategories. All the attributes will remain same like price and discount, but I want to change the product image whenever the product is viewed in different subcategories. For if I upload a phone case Design for iPhone it should display different product image for all the iPhone models which are subcategories in my case. Please help me with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just create variant product and create variation with model no. and enter all information same for all variant other then image
it may resolve your issue

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have used gallery swatcher for  switching images but it only works on attributes not on categories, can you please elaborate your answer.